# Event triggers on multiple elements instead one in *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, behaviorsubject

In my Angular2 app I've got following code for the **'view'**:

```
<ul class="cart">
    <li *ngFor="let item of cartService.cart$ | async">//BehaviorSubject
        <h3 class="title">{{item.title}}</h3>
        <span class="descr">{{item.description}}</span>

         <button (click)="decrQnt()">-</button>

           <form action="#">
             <input type="text" maxlength="3" id="qnt" readonly="readonly" value="{{qnt}}">
            </form>

          <button (click)="incrQnt()">+</button>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

In **component.ts**:

```
public qnt: number = 1;

incrQnt(){
   this.qnt < 100 ? ++this.qnt : 0;
}

decrQnt(){
    this.qnt > 1 ? this.qnt-- : 0;
 }
```

The problem is that my functions work simultaneously for all elements in my view created by ***ngFor** And I need, of course, to increment / decrement quantity of only one element which button is clicked.

I tried to pass 'item' as an argument to the trigger functions, but then I had *Property 'item' does not exist on type AppComponent*

In the view tried to change {{qnt}} to {{item.qnt}} and got *Can't read property qnt of undefined*

I guess it's because of using BehaviorSubject, because other properties such as item.description and item.title are passed via json, while qnt is initialized on the run.

But how to deal with it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect each item ahs its own `qnt` property
Your increment/decrement function could also pass in the respective `item` you want the operation on

```
<button (click)="decrQnt(item)">-</button>  
<button (click)="incrQnt(item)">+</button>  


incrQnt(item){
   item.qnt < 100 ? ++item.qnt : 0;
}

decrQnt(item){
    item.qnt > 1 ? item.qnt-- : 0;
 }
```

Comment: Nothing's changed, nothing's shown in console. I just put there console.log function to test behavior, and it works, but the increment / decrement functions neither work nor call any errors in console.

Comment: I had to add property qnt in my json object (which I would like to add on the run in the beginning) and everything got alright